# Брать новости из news.yandex.ru

Tags: php, парсер, яндекс-новости

Нужно брать новости с `news.yandex.ru`, по своему запросу, например

```
http://news.yandex.ru/yandsearch?grhow=clutop&text=какой-то_запрос&rpt=nnews2&p=0
```

Но беда в том что яндекс при частых запросах просит капчу, подскажите как быть? Если какие нибудь способы.
Подойдут еще варианты с mail.ru

PS. Это все на php

Comment: Используйте прокси для подмены своего IP.

Comment: Зачем брать? Пусть сами приходят в почту (в результатах поиска справа ссылка "Читать результаты запроса «XYZ» в Подписках в Яндекс.Почте"). А уж принять и распарсить письмо всяко проще, чем возиться с запросами/капчами.

Comment: может человек делает свой сервис по поиску новостей.

Comment: Тогда имеет смысл смотреть в сторону API + RSS для предварительного заполнения базы, и чего-то типа сфинкса для уточняющих запросов.

Answer (score 1):

Однозначно посмотрите в сторону RSS, которые доступны для Яндекса и Mail.ru. 
Например,[Яндекс](http://news.yandex.by/export.html).
Есть ещё вариант найти веб-сервисы, который отдают эти самые новости для того же Яндекса, но это более сложный способ.

Успехов.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "прокси:порт");
```

[ТЫК](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php) - Больше инфы

Используйте прокси.

Comment: Публичных проксей, маскирующих IP, не так уж и много. А пользователей у них ещё больше. Так что это только отсрочит неизбежное.